# Crop Multiple templates from single image at the same time

Tags: photo-editing, automation

Hello guys i'm working on a template matching project using OpenCV (a computer vision software library), so i need to take a lot of templates of one map image, in the fact about 300 templates. This is very difficult manually. I have tried different approaches, but I'm still looking for a tool to do something like this:

[image]

In other words I need all template boundaries(red squares) to be on screen and once i finish my work, I like to crop and save all of them with one command. If this is possible,  which application should I use? Photoshop, Illustrator, GIMP or something else?

Comment: Who draws those red rectangles - a piece of software or you? If it is software, it surely can be augmented to save the snippet.

Comment: No it's me just for clarify

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be useful:

In **Illustrator** it's possible to create multiple overlapping artboards by using the *Artboard Tool*.

[image: Mutiple artboard in Illustrator]

When you export with *File > Export*, remember to check "Use Artboards" to export the separate artboards.

[image: Export]

This way you can save all your crops at once.

[image: Resulting files]

Comment: That is a genius solution!  I never would have thought of using artboards like that!